# Is there a way to block access to a certain hostname wholesystemly without root using only adb commands?

Tags: root-access, connection-issues, hosts, url, webview

Editing 'hosts' file is not possible without root and I am not satisfied with either local or remote VPN block. Is there a way to block all outgoing connections to a certain remote URL address without root access wholesystemly so all apps (even system ones) won't be able to make a connection to this address?

Comment: There are some apps outside Play Store which allow ad blocking based on a local VPN (redirect all traffic through the app, but not to a remote server). Such apps usually also allow to use custom block lists. AFAK Blokada 4 allows to use custom block lists, nut sure if this feature is finally available in Blokada 5.